# Will ActiveSync 4.1 work with ArcPad 10.0.2?

Tags: arcpad, arcgis-10.0

Because Microsoft's ActiveSync 4.5 will not work on machines with Windows XP (SP3), from what I've read I need to install ActiveSync 4.1.  Has anyone tested this on ArcPad 10.0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcPad 10.1 requires ActiveSync 4.5

**ActiveSync 4.5** on Windows SP3 requires you to upgrade the original installer to Windows installer 4.5

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942288

Note:
**Make sure your Firewall is switched off during install.**

**ArcPadTeam** blog has helpful information (not sure why this content is not on the main ESRI site)
http://arcpadteam.blogspot.com/2010/10/latest-versions-of-software-firmware.html

Comment: ok so once we download Windows Installer 4.5 we 
will be able to load Active Sync 4.5 on Windows XP SP3? Also, you mention 10.1 requires ActiveSync 4.5, I assume it's the same for 10.0.2?

Comment: yes it is working for Windows XP SP3 (with upgraded installer) and 10.0.2